# Changing route in function with react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm new to react and I would like to set a routing for my application.
I work with react-router-dom and I have a connection component and a create component.
I would like to redirect the user on create once he is logged in. Here is my code :

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link
} from "react-router-dom";
import Aproove from "aproove/aproove";

import './App.css';
import Connection from './components/Connection';
import Create from './components/Create';
import Settings from './components/Settings';

const App = (props) => {

  const [file, setFile] = useState(window.getFile);
  const [aproove, setAproove] = useState(new Aproove());

  //Get called when the user press "Connect" in connection component
  const handleConnect = (email, password) => {
    aproove.login(email, password).then(result => verifyConnection(result.data.result));
  }

  const verifyConnection = (result) => {
    if(result!=="") {
      console.log("validated");
      //If conenction validated, redirect to create route
      handleLocation("create");
    }
    else console.log("rejected");
  }

  const handleLocation = (path) => {
    //Write here how to change route in function
  } 

  return (
    <Router>
    <div>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link to="/connection">Connection</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/create">Create</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/settings">Settings</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>

      {/* A <Switch> looks through its children <Route>s and
          renders the first one that matches the current URL. */}
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/connection">
          <Connection 
          onConnect={handleConnect}/>
        </Route>
        <Route path="/create">
          <Create />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/settings">
          <Settings />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </div>
  </Router>
  );

}

export default App;
```

I already tried with history hook but without any success.

Thank you for any help ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the useHistory hook (https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks) or the Redirect (https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Redirect).

Comment: thx, i managed to make it work with redirect, thank you !